# Defining a new command that automats drawing certain braids inTikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, braids

I would like to define a new command, `braids`, that allows me to automatically draw some braid-like paths in tikz.

Examples of said paths are for example in the paper 
"[Algebras and Hopf algebras in braided tensor categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9509023)" by Shahn Majid:

- Proof of Lemma 2.1,Lemma 2.3 and Theorem 3.9.
- Equation (8): Here we have three strands. One can easily see the difference between 'strand one crossing over strand two and *then* crossing over strand three' and 'strand one crossing over strand two *and* three'.

I'm interested in defining a command `braids` that takes 4 arrays of nodes, A,B,C,D and two arrays E,F, that specify the drawing style, as parameters. In pseudo-code `braids` should work like this:

```
\newcommand{braids}[6]{

    if( size(A) = size(B) = size(E) AND size(C) = size(D) = size(F) ){
        while size(A)>0{

            pointX  = removeLastEntryOf(A);
            pointY  = removeLastEntryOf(B);
            styleXY = removeLastEntryOf(E);

            draw[styleXY] pointX -- pointY;

        }
        while size(C)>0{

            pointX  = removeLastEntryOf(C);
            pointY  = removeLastEntryOf(D);
            styleXY = removeLastEntryOf(F);

            drawWhitePathForOverCrossing(pointX, point Y);
            draw[styleXY] pointX -- pointY;

        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is twofold:
How do I work with arrays/lists in LaTeX? 
How would/could I define the `drawWhitePathForOverCrossing` command?

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/braids ?

Comment: If you can represent the braids as a series of repeated segments, you could make a decoration.

Comment: @Henri Menke Sadly braids doesn't do the job for me. Specifically I need pictures that represent  'strad 1 goes over strand 2,3,...' instead of 'strand 1 goes over strand 2 and then over strand 4 and then....'. However if this would be possible to do with braids I'd be more than happy.

Comment: @SeHa There is also `knots` as part of https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3 . That's more flexible than `braids`.

Comment: There are some other knot packages, too, I think, though they may be more designed for specific uses. But isn't 'strand 1 goes over strand 2, 3 ...' just 'strand 1 goes over strand 2 and then over strand 3 ...'?

Comment: @cfr The problem with this approach is, that pictures can get very large if braidings are split up in a sequence like this.
 (One could of course scale the braidings down but that would reduce readability I guess).

Comment: I guess I'm rather confused, then, as I'm not clear what 'over 2,3' should look like if not 'over 2 and then over 3'. Maybe you could draw something with `braids` and then post the code, explaining how you'd like to change the output.

Comment: @cfr I edited my original question. See the paper by Majid that I've mentioned.

Comment: This isn't currently possible with the `braids` package, but has been a feature request for a while.  At present, I would use the `knots` package.  Another option would be to use the configuration options of the `braids` package to reduce the height of the crossings (this might need the more recent version from [github](https://github.com/loopspace/braids), I don't recall right now).